# Screen casting alternative to Google Cast?

Tags: android, chromecast

I used Google cast to cast my phone's screen. That worked. But all4, the Channel 4 catch-up app, wouldn't display on the second screen. A message popped up saying "all 4 doesn't work on secondary screens". Trying to cast from the all4 app threw "this is not available for cast".

Is there another app which can just cast the whole screen? The s5 screen mirroring didn't seem to detect the Chromecast at all. To be clear, I need an app which can cast the screen like Google cast does. An app which only casts local files or streams from specific providers is no good.

We're talking s5 android, touchwiz, rooted, xposed. If you have any idea how to stop Google cast from snitching to other apps, please let me know here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157427/how-do-i-prevent-apps-from-blocking-a-second-screen

Edit: I've tried several apps from Play, including secondscreen, but they all just try to use the s5's native screen mirroring ability. This doesn't even detect my Chromecast. Don't know why, because the screen mirroring works fine on other tvs I've tried that have native screen mirroring. If other people can get it s5 native screen mirroring to talk to Chromecast, I'd love to know how they managed it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest

http://www.allcast.io/

this is developed by CloclWorkMod is a free Android and iOS application that lets you stream your photos and videos to your TV using a third-party DLNA receiver. This free app supports Chromecast, Apple TV, Roku Streaming stick, Amazon Fire TV and more devices.

**Why consider this over Chromecast?**
This app is not a replacement for Chromecast, instead an add-on for it. With this free app, and using Chromecast or any pther DLNA receiver, you can stream your local content to your TV.

**Notable features:** Stream locally stored media files to your TV using a third-party DLNA receiver.

**Pricing:** *Free Android and iOS application*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "SecondScreen"? the link to it is here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farmerbb.secondscreen.free&hl=en

Info:
SecondScreen is an application designed for power users that frequently connect their Android devices to external displays. It works with your existing screen mirroring solution to give you the best experience possible. With SecondScreen, you can change your device's resolution and density to fit your TV or monitor, enable always-on desktop mode in Chrome, and even turn your device's backlight off, among several other features.

Comment: Good thought, but unfortunately that just tries to use native screen mirroring, like all the others I've found, see edit for details.